# Continues Counter - traffic counter reporting

Tags: shell-script

I'm currently in the process of writing small solution which would continuously receive output from transactions trace (traffic trace) in UNIX it would count/monitor traffic.

The below is production example:

```
103022|210|???->???   |50.000     |400|9/11|Response Timed Out !

103035|110|???->???   |17.000     |400|9/11|Response Timed Out !

103104|210|???->???   |20.000     |400|9/11|Response Timed Out !

103105|110|???->???   |6.500      |400|9/11|Response Timed Out !
```

etc...

I need to make a continuous counter for the timeout transactions.
Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Anas. Can you please clarify the question? How is that output produced? Is it written to a file, or is it the stdout of a command?

Comment: *'grep -hci response.timed.out traffic.log'* or from stdout *'cat traffic.log | grep -hci response.timed.out'*